# Show results if Inner Join is empty

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables that I am joining with an Inner join.

The first table is a list of locations, and the second is a list of products at each location.

My issue is when I run the inner join, if there is a location without any products that location will not show up.

Basically if nothing is in the inner join, it essentially doesn't exist.

```
SELECT idL, n, lat,lng, latest, type, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('33.111963') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians(lng ) - radians('-117.281985') ) + sin( radians('33.111963') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM Table1 
inner join(SELECT ids, max(dateTime) as latest FROM Table2 GROUP BY ids ) as tableJ 
on idL = ids 
WHERE type = "Grocery" 
GROUP BY idL 
HAVING distance < '15' 
ORDER BY distance asc
```

The SQL might look kinda crazy because its calculating distance from the place too.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySql? Why are you doing a `Group By`? Why is there a `Having` and a `Where` clause ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` to be able to get rows from left table when there is no matching rows in right table. Keep in mind that all columns from right table will be NULL in that case.

Answer (score 1):

A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would be the correct "`JOIN`" type to use in this situation.

> Left outer join produces a complete set of records from Table A, with the matching records (where available) in Table B. If there is no match, the right side will contain null.

[Futher explanation of Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)